# How to get an element that has no ID with node.js nightmare

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I recently started using nightmare, and I am having issues getting information that doesn't have an ID or something
For example, I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="reg">
```

This is a button, how can I `.click()` on it through nightmare?

Comment: Where does this element appear in the page? You can reference elements in relation to _other_ elements, so its context is important. Failing that, use a CSS selector that can target the "name" or "value" field.

Comment: Ah, thank you. It's part of a table so I will just fetch the table and go to the row the button is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css attribute selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
document.querySelector('input[name=reg]');
```

Comment: Didn't think of using the name. Thank you!